# What is <MvcProjectUpgradeChecked> Element in csproj file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, csproj

I have just opened my existing application in `VS 2015 RC` and after some automatic upgradations check, it added the following lines in the csproj file of the project.

```
<MvcProjectUpgradeChecked>true</MvcProjectUpgradeChecked>
<FileUpgradeFlags>
</FileUpgradeFlags>
<UpgradeBackupLocation>
</UpgradeBackupLocation>
<OldToolsVersion>4.0</OldToolsVersion>
```

I was wondering what does these line do? Can I check them in safely to the source control assuming that anyone else opening the solution can open it in some previous versions of Visual Studio ?

I was unable to find anything on MSDN for this tag

**UPDATE**

I just opened the solution after csproj modifications in `Visual Studio 2013` and it opened without any issue, so this seems to be just a flag. But, nonetheless, can anybody share some definition for this?

Answer (score 6):

The project migration tool writes this so that you will only get the "limited MVC support" warning dialog one time.  This is actually an artifact from earlier migration functionality; the project type used to be changed from one flavor to another, now older MVC projects are changed to WAPs (Web Application Projects) which would not trigger the "limited" dialog.  However, if you delete it, the migration report will pop open the next time you open the project.

The other tags shown are also artifacts of file migration wizard when it creates the migration report and creates a backup of the project prior to modifying any files.